# NextJS with Nginx

Tags: reactjs, nginx, next.js, routes

I would appreciate help with the problem I have.
I have an application written in NextJS and when I run it and connect by IP:Port it works fine,
When I try to connect with Nginx there is a problem that some files are not found because the route is incorrect
Would appreciate help,
Attached are the code snippets.

In Nginx

```
    server {
        listen 80 default_server;
                listen [::]:80 default_server;
                server_name _;
        
                include /etc/nginx/default.d/*.conf;

                location / {
                }

            location /nextjs/ {
                 proxy_pass http://{IP}:{PORT}/;
            }       
        
        error_page 404 /404.html;
                location = /40x.html {
                }

                error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
                location = /50x.html {
                }
    }
```

[image of the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LvWQa.png)

I tried several things and it didn't help.
Maybe someone encountered something similar

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.